# Error in Twitter intregration with Java code?

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

Hello every one i am working on twitter API twitter4j . I want to send Twitt on my twitter account by my java code but when i try to compile it i get some error which i dont understand 
my java code

```
public class entry {
    public static void main(String ar[])throws TwitterException, IOException
    {
        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true);
        cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("dJGC64ozxFNfs7D3LK07oA");
        cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("ExvnfE8AOM5vjqdjANoRdZyLKSOo2LZyHnxo2ERWzOs");
        cb .setOAuthAccessToken("*****************************");
        cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("**************************");
        Twitter tf=new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
        tf.updateStatus("test ! ");
    }
}
```

Error Which i am geting when i try to compile my code :

```
Exception in thread "main" A JSONObject text must begin with '{' found:
at 2 [character 3 line 1]
Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=6f994c35 or
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[6f994c35-006e990b 1b2aeabf-9f2c6cb7], statusCode=-1, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.3}
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpResponse.asJSONObject(HttpResponse.java:153)
    at twitter4j.internal.json.StatusJSONImpl.<init>(StatusJSONImpl.java:66)
    at twitter4j.internal.json.z_T4JInternalJSONImplFactory.createStatus(z_T4JInternalJSONImplFactory.java:69)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.updateStatus(TwitterImpl.java:241)
    at twiterapplication.entry.main(entry.java:29)
Caused by: twitter4j.internal.org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' found:
http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=006e990b
```

Comment: Which is line 29 of `entry.java`? (Hint: class names should start with an upper case letter like `Entry`.)

Comment: code at line 29 tf.updateStatus("test ! ");

Comment: Is there any solution sir

Comment: can you paste the code with line no , or simply mention which line is line-29 ?? ..... oops saw your comment later

Comment: tf.updateStatus("test ! ");
it is a code on line 29 sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking at [this implementation](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/8226).

Comment: thank you so much for giving answer on my question sir but problem still same sir

Comment: here's another thread I found that may be helpful. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/twitter4j/la9P0lPVyH4

Comment: Thank you very much sir when i do the following change then 1 exception from above is been remove but one exception still remains a
same
exception is :
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[4adef3f6-00a4bea5 3ba5a640-6a6f93d1], statusCode=-1, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.3}

Answer (score 0):

OK well thank you so much to all guys who answer my question finally i my code is working now my twit’s is showing on my id. I do only some following simple changes on my code and now my code is working fine

my code is :

```
Twitter twitter= new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
twitter.setOAuthConsumer("************", "*************");
AccessToken newAccessToken = new AccessToken("******","*********");
System.out.println(newAccessToken);
twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(newAccessToken);
String s=twitter.getScreenName();
Status myStatus = twitter.updateStatus("Your message here");
```

This code is working fine now i call  setOAuthConsumer with the twitter object and create the object of AccessToken and pass its object into the setOAuthAccessToken with twitter object and my code is working fine thanxx a lot for all guyzz one again 
 Marco Corona sir your answer help me a lot. Thank you